Can an ellipse roll down a tilted sine curve without jumping?
Background
Assume that we have a solid ellipse with uniform density, and that it rolls along a curve.
In the following MO question, I asked along what curve an ellipse rolls down fastest. It was pointed out that one first needs to find any curve the ellipse rolls down from, without losing contact from the curve and jumping up and down. One can consider this as a variation of the classical Brachistochrone problem.
Now, it turns out that there are various curves along which an ellipse can roll horizontally. These are described in this video by Morphocular. It turns out that, if one wants to describe the equation of the curve along which an ellipse with width $2a$ and height $2b$ rolls down horizontally with the center as its axle point, the $x$-coordinate of this parametric equation comes down to an elliptic integral (see the video at 5:04):
$$x = \int \frac{b}{\sqrt{1-\epsilon^{2} \cos^{2}(t)}} dt \label{1}\tag{1} $$
This is not an easy expression to deal with. However, there is a way out if one chooses the foci as the axle points, instead of the center of the ellipse. Assume that the ellipse has width $1$ and height $\sqrt{2}$. In this case, we can describe the curve with a simple sine wave, with period $\pi$ and amplitude $1/2$. Here is a picture (a snapshot from the video at 7:39):
                                                
The equation of this curve can thus be described succinctly as $$y = \frac{1}{2} \sin(2x) .\label{2}\tag{2}$$
Question
Now, suppose that we tilt this sine curve and the ellipse by an angle of $\theta$. In the image below, I have visualized the setting. (Note that the shape of the sine curve is different from the one above. However, this is merely due to my mediocre illustration skills. It is supposed to describe the same curve as the one shown in the image above. The same applies to the ellipse.)

I have the following questions:

For what values of $\theta$ does the curve roll down without losing contact with the tilted sine curve — if any?
If there are multiple values of $\theta$ for which the ellipse rolls down properly, I wonder: for what value does the ellipse roll down the fastest?

Note
I've also asked this question a while ago on MSE.

Wouldn't it get an ever-increasing momentum from crests to crests and always lose contact after a while, whatever $\theta>0$ is? By the way I would tilt the gravity instead to keep the nice initial coordinates.

@ClaudeChaunier That may be the case, but to be sure, it is to be determined mathematically

It is a mathematical consequence of classical mechanics, because the gravitational potential energy is linearly decreasing from crest to crest. Therefore translational plus rotational kinetic energy is linearly increasing. They are proportional to the square of translational and rotational speeds, which are in a constant ratio. Hence the speed is going to increase as the square root of the crest number. Anyway it keeps your question very interesting. I wonder at which crest number the ellipse is going to take off, as a function of $\theta$.

In other words the motion seen from crest to crest amounts to a free fall augmented with a similar rotational speed-up as far as the ellipse keeps rolling. The constant gravity force is then necessarily going to be overwhelmed by the body inertia and won't be able to keep it down, when the center of mass moves in a direction above the contact tangent direction.

@ClaudeChaunier The question regarding the crest number at which the ellipse is going to take off (as a function of $\theta$), indeed seems like an interesting one. I am curious about your possible answer(s)

While I am working out details I notice the translational and rotational speeds at the gravity center are not in a constant ratio I handwaved -- you were right to ask for mathematics. By the way, the formulas get nice by rolling an ellipse of semi-axes $a>b=1$ on the curve $y=c\cdot\cos x;$ with one focus $F$ staying on the line $y=a$, where $c = \sqrt{a^2-1}$ is also the distance between $F$ and the ellipse center. Well, the general formulas get nice, except for the translational speed, which looks messy. Considering only $c=1$, $a=\sqrt{2}$ doesn't seem to help.
